# Nodejs y Mysql, No me resuelve un SQL=Select

Tags: mysql, nodejs, angularjs

Estoy realizando una aplicación, donde uso NodeJs y MySQL, sin embargo a pesar de que ya me pude conectar a la base de datos e insertar registros, al realizar un Select desde una ruta diferente me envia el siguiente error.

Server on Port 4000
DB is Connected
<ref *1> Query {
_events: [Object: null prototype] {},
_eventsCount: 0,
_maxListeners: undefined,
_callback: undefined,
_callSite: Error
at Pool.query (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:199:23)
at C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\src\routes\links.js:27:49
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (C:\wamp\www\nodejsAppMySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3),
_ended: false,
_timeout: undefined,
_timer: Timer { _object: [Circular *1], _timeout: null },
sql: 'SELECT * FROM links',
values: undefined,
typeCast: true,
nestTables: false,
_resultSet: null,
_results: [],
_fields: [],
_index: 0,
_loadError: null,
[Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}

Les adjunto mi codigo por si alguien sabe cual es mi problema:

```
const express =  require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require ('../database');
router.get('/add', (req,res) =>
                   {
                    //    res.send('form');
                       res.render('links/add');
                   });

                   
  router.post('/add', async (req,res) =>
                     {
                        const {title,url, description} = req.body;
                        const newLink = { title
                                         ,url
                                         ,description};
                        await pool.query('INSERT INTO links set ?', [newLink]);
                        res.send('enviado');      
 
                    });   
                    
   router.get('/', async (req, res) =>
   { 
   const links = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM links');  
   console.log(links); 
                       res.send('las listas iran Aqui');                       
                     });   
                   
module.exports = router;
```

El problema se presenta al ejecutar esta

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) =>
{ 
cont links = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM links');  
console.log(links); 
res.send('las listas iran Aqui');                       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es por una actualización de https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql (MYSQL)

Tu codigo sería

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => { 
  const links = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM links', function(error,results,fields){
   if (error) throw error;
   console.log(results); //Pinta por consola los resultados de tu consulta
   res.send("Las listas irán aqui")
  });
});
```

**Información extraida de https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections**